# Is it possible to set a drawable as background without distortion?

Tags: android

I am having a vertical LinearLayout with many TextViews in there. Now I want to have a check-icon in front of all of them, which can be checked or unchecked.

```
[x] test1
[ ] test2
[x] test2
[ ] test4
```

Is there a way to do that without any additional views? In html you would set the background image for the TextViews, but when I do that in android, the background graphic gets distorted.

Comment: You should use a `CheckedTextView` instead of a regular `TextView`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use either android:drawableLeft="@drawable/yourcheckimage" on your TextView item in your XML layout

or

Use one of the setCompoundDrawablesXXX methods of TextView to accomplish this programmatically.